# How to compute relative homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology

How to compute relative homology group  $H_n(SO(n),SO(n)-E_n)$

I try to use the long exact sequence as follows $$
...H_n(SO(n)-E_n)\rightarrow H_n(SO(n))\rightarrow H_n(SO(n),SO(n)-E_n) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(SO(n)-E_n)...$$
I find difficulty both in compute $H_n(SO(n))$ and  $H_n(SO(n)-E_n)$

Comment: What is $E_n$ ?

Comment: the Unitary matrix

Comment: You mean the identity?

Comment: yes,you are right

Comment: Maybe you can try by excising?

Comment: could you show me more

Comment: $SO(n)$ is a manifold, the identity has a neighborhhod isomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $d$ is the dimension of $SO(n)$ (easy to compute).
Let $B$ be the complement of this neighborhood. Apply excision to the pairs $(SO(n), SO(n)-E_n)$ and $(SO(n)-B, (SO(n)-E_n)-B)\simeq(\mathbb{B}^d, \mathbb{B}^d-\{center\})$

Comment: could you help me show why $(SO(n)-B, (SO(n)-E_n)-B)\simeq(\mathbb{B}^d, \mathbb{B}^d-\{center\})$

Comment: It's simply how we chose $B$. It is the complement of neighborhood isomorphic to a ball.